# Unable to format disk partition: 'The system cannot find the file specified'

Tags: windows, windows-10, formatting, disk-management

I dual boot with Ubuntu and Windows 10.

I was deleting the 82.76GB and 14.90GB partitions in which my Ubuntu exists, but it is giving the error "the system cant find the file specified".

What should I will do?

[image]